Why can't I move a closure represented by a trait?
I am trying to implement some parsing combinators. Each parser combinator is a mutable closure but outside code refers to each combinator as a trait that provides a blanket implementation for calling the combinator function.
// Region of external code, CANNOT modify

type ParseResult<I, T> = Result<(I, T), String>;

trait Parser<T> {
    fn parse<'a>(&mut self, input: &'a str) -> ParseResult<&'a str, T>;
}

// Blanket implementation for parser combinators
impl<F, T> Parser<T> for F
where F: FnMut(&str) -> ParseResult<&str, T> {
    fn parse<'a>(&mut self, input: &'a str) -> ParseResult<&'a str, T> {
        self(input)
    }
}

// Example of an external combinator
fn external_combinator<P, T>(parser: P) -> impl FnMut(&str) -> ParseResult<&str, T>
where P: Parser<T> {
    preceded_by(char_parser('a'), parser)
}

// My code begins here

fn char_parser(c: char) -> impl Fn(&str) -> ParseResult<&str, char> {
    move |input: &str| {
        let Some(rest) = input.strip_prefix(c) else {
            return Err(format!("Input does not begin with {c}"));
        };
        Ok((rest, c))
    }
}

fn delimited_by<Extracted>(
    begin_char: char,
    final_char: char,
    mut parser: impl Parser<Extracted>
) -> impl FnMut(&str) -> ParseResult<&str, Extracted> {
    move |input: &str| {
        let parse_begin = char_parser(begin_char);

        // Why cannot I move parser to preceded_by?          <-- ERROR HERE
        let precede = preceded_by(parse_begin, &mut parser);

        let parse_final = char_parser(final_char);
        followed_by(precede, parse_final)(input)
    }
}

fn followed_by<Extracted, _Discard>(
    mut parser_a: impl Parser<Extracted>,
    mut parser_b: impl Parser<_Discard>
) -> impl FnMut(&str) -> ParseResult<&str, Extracted> {
    move |input: &str| {
        let (rest, new_value) = parser_a.parse(input)?;
        let (rest, _) = parser_b.parse(rest)?;
        Ok((rest, new_value))
    }
}

fn preceded_by<Extracted, _Discard>(
    mut parser_a: impl Parser<_Discard>,
    mut parser_b: impl Parser<Extracted>
) -> impl FnMut(&str) -> ParseResult<&str, Extracted> {
    move |input: &str| {
        let (rest, _) = parser_a.parse(input)?;
        parser_b.parse(rest)
    }
}

// Region of external code, cannot modify
fn main() {
    let my_combinator = delimited_by('a', 'b', char_parser('c'));
    let mut final_combinator = external_combinator(my_combinator);

    match final_combinator("data") {
        Ok(_) => println!("OK"),
        Err(_) => println!("Error")
    }
}

When I try to compile this demo, I get the following errors.
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&mut impl Parser<Extracted>: Parser<_>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:43:48
   |
43 |         let precede = preceded_by(parse_begin, &mut parser);
   |                       -----------              ^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `for<'a> FnMut(&'a str)` is not implemented for `impl Parser<Extracted>`, which is required by `&mut impl Parser<Extracted>: Parser<_>`
   |                       |
   |                       required by a bound introduced by this call
   |
   = note: required for `&mut impl Parser<Extracted>` to implement `for<'a> FnOnce(&'a str)`
note: required for `&mut impl Parser<Extracted>` to implement `Parser<_>`
  --> src/main.rs:10:12
   |
10 | impl<F, T> Parser<T> for F
   |            ^^^^^^^^^     ^
11 | where F: FnMut(&str) -> ParseResult<&str, T> {
   |                         -------------------- unsatisfied trait bound introduced here
note: required by a bound in `preceded_by`
  --> src/main.rs:63:24
   |
61 | fn preceded_by<Extracted, _Discard>(
   |    ----------- required by a bound in this function
62 |     mut parser_a: impl Parser<_Discard>,
63 |     mut parser_b: impl Parser<Extracted>
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `preceded_by`
help: consider further restricting this bound
   |
37 |     mut parser: impl Parser<Extracted> + for<'a> FnMut(&'a str)
   |                                        ++++++++++++++++++++++++

I tried applying + for<'a> FnMut(&'a str) but it leads to more errors and in the end the compiler wants me to change the Parser<T> but I cannot do that because in production Parser<T> is provided by an external code.
I have a few questions:

How can I pass the parameter parser from delimited_by to preceded_by without using dyn or Box?
If I can't, can I rewrite my code to satisfy the trait in external_combinator? Remember, I can't change the signature or the implementation of anything in the external region.
If you have at least a more beginner-friendly explanation of why I cannot pass the parameter parser, please post it, that would be helpful too.


Solution 1: The intuitive way
I'll start with a solution that only involves the type of small fixes that result from addressing specific compiler errors.
First, note that, in delimited_by, &mut (impl SomeTrait) does not implement SomeTrait. Our first modification is to remove mut and &mut:
fn delimited_by<Extracted>(
    begin_char: char,
    final_char: char,
    parser: impl Parser<Extracted> // removed mut
) -> impl FnMut(&str) -> ParseResult<&str, Extracted> {
    move |input: &str| {
        let parse_begin = char_parser(begin_char);

        let precede = preceded_by(parse_begin, parser); // removed &mut

        let parse_final = char_parser(final_char);
        followed_by(precede, parse_final)(input)
    }
}

Now, we encounter a second problem. When a function takes impl SomeTrait, in this case impl Parser<Extracted>, Rust defaults to assuming no extra traits like Copy or Clone. This means that parser cannot be implicitly or explicitly duplicated, respectively. However, since delimited_by returns a closure that needs parser every time it executes, we do need multiple copies or clones of parser.
We can add a Clone bound to the argument, allowing us to clone it each time the closure runs. We must also explicitly say that char_parser returns a Cloneable function.
fn char_parser(c: char) -> impl Fn(&str) -> ParseResult<&str, char> + Clone // Added Clone {
    move |input: &str| {
        let Some(rest) = input.strip_prefix(c) else {
            return Err(format!("Input does not begin with {c}"));
        };
        Ok((rest, c))
    }
}

fn delimited_by<Extracted>(
    begin_char: char,
    final_char: char,
    parser: impl Parser<Extracted> + Clone // Added Clone
) -> impl FnMut(&str) -> ParseResult<&str, Extracted> {
    move |input: &str| {
        let parse_begin = char_parser(begin_char);

        let precede = preceded_by(parse_begin, parser.clone()); // Added clone

        let parse_final = char_parser(final_char);
        followed_by(precede, parse_final)(input)
    }
}

If you run final_combinator on "aacb", it parses!
Solution 2: The better way
Here is a solution that is more efficient, and doesn't require Clone. It accomplishes this by building the parsing machinery outside the repeatedly-executing closure:
fn delimited_by<Extracted>(
    begin_char: char,
    final_char: char,
    parser: impl Parser<Extracted>
) -> impl FnMut(&str) -> ParseResult<&str, Extracted> {
    let parse_begin = char_parser(begin_char);
    let precede = preceded_by(parse_begin, parser);
    let parse_final = char_parser(final_char);
    let mut parser = followed_by(precede, parse_final);
    move |input: &str| {
        parser(input)
    }
}

This can be abbreviated by factoring out the closure:
fn delimited_by<Extracted>(
    begin_char: char,
    final_char: char,
    parser: impl Parser<Extracted>
) -> impl FnMut(&str) -> ParseResult<&str, Extracted> {
    let parse_begin = char_parser(begin_char);
    let precede = preceded_by(parse_begin, parser);
    let parse_final = char_parser(final_char);
    followed_by(precede, parse_final)
}

